# reverse object value and boolean - 2 codes Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, boolean, reverse

i'm spending way too much time on trying to figure these 2 codes out.
i'm too burn out. i spent the last 2 hrs and lots of hours trying to figure out why Code 1 doesn't accept. And for Code 2, it accepted, but i'm not too sure.

**Code 1.**

Given an input Object, how might we loop over the Object IN REVERSE and 
print its values using console.log()?

```
function printObjectValuesInReverse(object) {
    var myArray = [];
    for(var keys in object) {
        myArray.push(object[keys]);
    } 
    for(var i = keys.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(keys[i]);
    }
```

**Code 2**

Given an Array of Strings and a Function designed to test the String in some way and return a Boolean on whether it passed, return true if ALL Strings pass the test.

```
function allStringsPass(strings, test) {
    for (var i =0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if(test(strings[i]) === false) {
            return false;
        } 
    } 
    return true;
```

Comment: Both your functions are missing the `}` at the end.

Comment: There's no order to the properties of an object, so it makes no sense to talk about looping over it in reverse.

Comment: `keys` isn't an array, I don't know why you're looping over it. You should be looping over `myArray` in reverse.

Comment: `Code 2` looks like it will be correct if you add the missing `}`.

Comment: first week of bootcamp. i'm still learning. lol thank you for the tips

Comment: barmar. thank you so much. what you said about key not being an array that helped alot!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `reverse` function. so your console.log will be `console.log(myArray.reverse())`

**Update** if you dont want to use a `reverse` function, your code should be like this

```js
function printObjectValuesInReverse(object) {
    var myArray = [];
    for(var keys in object) {
        myArray.push(object[keys]);
    } 
    for(var i = myArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(myArray[i]); // I changed this from keys[i]
    }
}
printObjectValuesInReverse({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
```

Comment: The homework is clearly intended to teach them how to code their own algorithms, not just use built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Code 1**

`keys` isn't an array. I think you might wanna iterate over `myArray`.

```
function printObjectValuesInReverse(object) {
    var myArray = [];
    for(var keys in object) {
        myArray.push(object[keys]);
    } 
    for(var i = myArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

**Code 2**

Just but the closing brace and it should work fine:

```
function allStringsPass(strings, test) {
    for (var i =0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if(test(strings[i]) === false) {
            return false;
        } 
    } 
    return true;
}
```